# Change the way a VBA script pastes data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script which loops in the following way:

If cell value is 3, then it will paste line 1 3 times, line 2 3 times,etc.

Current paste range looks like this:

```
Line 1
Line 1
Line 1

Line 2
Line 2
Line 2

Line 3
Line 3
Line 3
```

I was wondering whether the VBA script can paste the data so the data is in this manner:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

VBA script driving the above is as follows:

```
Sub CopyJournalLines2()

Dim wsInv As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer

Dim j As Integer
Dim iStartRow As Integer
Dim iNumCopies As Integer
Dim iCopyRow As Integer
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim PasteRange As Range

Set wsInv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Upload")

With wsInv
.Rows("17:5000").Cells.Clear
iStartRow = 17
iNumCopies = .Range("O12").Value
For i = 1 To 4
    Set CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 17))
    iCopyRow = iStartRow + (i - 1) * iNumCopies
    Set PasteRange = .Range(.Cells(iCopyRow, 1), .Cells(iCopyRow, 17))
    PasteRange.Formula = CopyRange.Formula

    For j = 2 To iNumCopies
        iCopyRow = iStartRow + j - 1 + (i - 1) * iNumCopies
        .Range(.Cells(iCopyRow, 1), .Cells(iCopyRow, 17)).FormulaR1C1 = PasteRange.FormulaR1C1

    Next j
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for ask your is much simpler, actually, since you are just pasting the same 4 line set `iNumCopies` of times.

Fully tested code:

```
Sub CopyJournalLines2()

Dim wsInv As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim iNumCopies As Integer, iCopyRow As Integer, iStartRow As Integer
Dim CopyRange As Range, PasteRange As Range

Set wsInv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Upload")

With wsInv

    .Rows("17:5000").Cells.Clear
    iStartRow = 17
    iNumCopies = .Range("O12").Value

    j = 0

    For i = 1 To iNumCopies

        .Range(.Range("A" & iStartRow).Offset(j), .Range("Q" & iStartRow + j + 3)).FormulaR1C1 = .Range("A1:Q4").FormulaR1C1

        'to paste formats and values use the following code
        '.Range("A1:Q4").Copy
        '.Range(.Range("A" & iStartRow).Offset(j), .Range("Q" & iStartRow + j + 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        '.Range(.Range("A" & iStartRow).Offset(j), .Range("Q" & iStartRow + j + 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

         j = j + 4

    Next i


End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Scott. Can you please tell me how to change the variable if I am changing it to 2 instead of 3 (to copy number of rows)?

Comment: @YameenSarwar - the number of copies is obtained from `Range("O12")` as you in your original code, so just adjust that value before running macro.

Comment: Hello Scott. Thanks again for the quick response. Do you know if there is a way to retain the original formatting of the lines being copied over? Also can you please tell me what this is referring to: Range("A1:Q4").FormulaR1C1

Comment: @YameenSarwar - see my edit for the code to paste values and formats. Take the comments out to get it to work (and comment out the first line). `Range("A1:Q4").FormulaR1C1` is the values of the lines to be copied that I surmised from your code. If this is off, adjust the range. It's also the same as saying `Range("A1:Q4").Value` because it's just values in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. It is very clear now. Is it possible to paste formulas and retain formula as I need both?

Comment: @YameenSarwar - Change `xlValues` to `xlFormulas`.

Comment: Line 1 gets copied to rows 2, 5, and 8. Line 2 gets copied to rows 3, 6, and 9. Line 3 gets copied to rows, 4, 7, and 10. This is fine.
 
The copied rows are fine but the value which is a formula is also skipping 3 lines. So say formula for line 1 copied to row 2, 5 and 8 should say O2, O3, O4, but instead the formula is changing with the loop and so the formula is actually showing O2, O5, O8