# run time error 5 and general copy/paste for loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am fairly new to VBA, but have moderate comfort with writing python. Declaring variables is a bit different between the two and I believe this is where the majority of my struggles lie.

This is a two-part headache:

1) The first headache is when I try to run the section of code below, I get "Run-time error'5': Invalid Procedure call or argument"

```
cll.Offset(0, 1).Copy (Worksheets("Sheet7").cells(Rows.Count & "L").End(xlUp).Row)
```

I have tried setting everything to the right of "copy" as a variable and then calling that variable, but I still receive the same error. I have looked at many tutorials and guides about referencing the last blank cell in a column and my code matches what I've found, though the error states otherwise.

2.) The bigger picture of code that I am working on features a drop down list (being used solely for referencing the 50 states), a code that references a state in that list, a `counta` worksheet function, and a separate worksheet that has every county in every state.

I want to select a state in the drop down, copy a particular state's county from a separate worksheet("Fips_Reference") to my activesheet("Sheet7"). From there I need it to reference my `counta` (pcount) and determine how many cells actually contain data. For example, if `counta` were to = 2, then I need each county pasted twice so that the column would read, from top to bottom, "County1" "County1" "County2" "County2" and so on. I have been working on trying to nest loops and if statements within each other for several days and continue to be stumped.

```
Sub fipsloop2()

pcount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("StateSource").Range("b3:b8"))


Dim cll As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim fip As Range
Dim state As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("FIPS_Reference").Range("c2:c3280")
Set fip = Worksheets("FIPS_Reference").Range("d2")
Set state = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C1")


For Each cll In rng
    If cll = state Then
        cll.Offset(0, 1).Copy (Worksheets("Sheet7").cells(Rows.Count & "L").End(xlUp).Row)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        'If pcount > 1 Then
    End If

Next


End Sub
```

I have arranged the for...each loop to look at a range of cells that contains the name of the state, and then look to see if the name of state matches the state in my list. If there is a match, it will offset to the right and copy the county value to a cell in my active workbook. I have tried combinations of do while and for each and if loops and logic, but I believe it is my naivety to VBA which is hurting me.

Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to copy an entire row? `cll.offset(0,1).EntireRow.Copy` may work.  Right now, you have a single value trying to be pasted to a `Row`. How to you want it to be pasted?

Comment: @BruceWayne I want to copy only that cell. I have been able to pull that reference through vba without a problem. However I was only able to paste the value into one cell and when it looped, it pasted into the same cell as before. That is why i wanted to add the snippet of code to look for the last empty cell in the column in which I wanted to paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to everything above. I am a genius! if anyone needs help going forward with a similar situation, please reference the code below and this link ([Change the way a VBA script pastes data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074439/change-the-way-a-vba-script-pastes-data))

```
Sub fipsloop2()

pcount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("StateSource").Range("b3:b8"))

Dim cll As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim fip As Range
Dim state As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer


Set rng = Worksheets("FIPS_Reference").Range("c2:c3280")
Set fip = Worksheets("FIPS_Reference").Range("d2")
Set state = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C1")

x = 3

For Each cll In rng
    If cll = state Then
        For i = 1 To pcount
            cll.Offset(0, 1).Copy (Worksheets("Sheet7").cells(x, 12))
            x = x + 1
        Next i
    End If
Next cll

End Sub
```